# How to get file create date in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using openrowset, I am loading the XML file to a temp table.

How do I get the file created date?

```
CREATE TABLE #T 
(
    IntCol int,
    XmlCol xml
);

INSERT INTO #T (XmlCol)
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'c:\Test.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x;

SELECT * FROM #t
```

Comment: I would use another language to read all the file informations but if you have to stick to SQL you may want to look [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic494395-149-1.aspx)

Comment: Thank you Xavier, for whatever reason ..we told not to use : exec master.dbo.xp_cmdshell

Comment: I am trying to get the details from openrowset

Comment: You may find it easier to add the file creation date to the XML file as part of the creation process!

Comment: we get the xml file from third party .. comes in as feed.

Answer (score 3):

Not the most concise way to do this, but using Ole Automation in SQL Server is one way to get this information. The following sample uses `C:\Temp\testfile.txt` as an example. This not really "SQL", don't know if this good enough for you.

```
DECLARE @hr INT;
DECLARE @dt_created DATETIME;
DECLARE @obj_file INT;
DECLARE @obj_file_system INT;
DECLARE @file_name VARCHAR(100)='C:\Temp\testfile.txt';

-- Create a FileSystemObject. Create this once for all subsequent file manipulation. Don't forget to destroy this object once you're done with file manipulation (cf cleanup)
EXEC @hr = sp_OACreate 'Scripting.FileSystemObject', @obj_file_system OUT;
IF @hr<>0 GOTO __cleanup;

-- Get a handle for the file. Don't forget to release the handle for each file you get a handle for (see cleanup). The return will be different from 0 if the file doesn't exist
EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @obj_file_system, 'GetFile', @obj_file out, @file_name;
IF @hr<>0 GOTO __print_created_date;

-- Retrieve the created date.
EXEC sp_OAGetProperty @obj_file, 'DateCreated', @dt_created OUT;

__print_created_date:
SELECT @dt_created AS file_date;

__cleanup:
EXEC sp_OADestroy @obj_file_system;
EXEC sp_OADestroy @obj_file;
```

Ole Automation needs to be enabled first though (just once):

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
sp_configure 'Ole Automation Procedures', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

T-SQL is not a language with which you can access file systems. However you can write a stored procedure in C# to accomplish this task. You would read the metadata with the appropriate classes in the .Net Framework. You can write a custom function with CLR integration to get every information you need from your filesystem.

Here is a little working sample to get an file created date with CLR integration in C#:

```
public class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    [SqlFunction]
    public static SqlDateTime GetCreatedDate(SqlString filePath)
    {
        return filePath.IsNull ? SqlDateTime.Null : File.GetCreationTime(filePath.Value);
    }
}
```

Then you've got to deploy the assembly and register it to SQL Server, then create the proper function with Create function commands.

see more in [CodeProject Sample](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/791953/SQL-CLR-functions)

Comment: Thank you.  We are able to get all the details from SQL. However , only missing part is File Created date. I am able to get that through master..XP_CMDShell  - we are not using the inbuilt sp .. for security reasons

Comment: @goofyui Could not you use from CLR?

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @f varchar(1000)='E:\work\share\data.txt';
declare @cmd varchar(1000)='for %a in ('+@f+') do echo %~ta'
  IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t1') IS NOT NULL
  DROP TABLE #t1
  create table #t1(_output varchar(1000))
  insert #t1
  exec xp_cmdshell @cmd
  declare @fileDate varchar(100)
  set @fileDate=(select _output from #t1 where _output not like '%echo%')
  print @fileDate
```

and convert @fileDate to dateTime by your settings